# Magento: frontend user login not working till 24 hours

Tags: magento-1.9, login

A newly registered user is not able to log in to Magento site. Magento version is `1.9.4`. I tried many methods but none of them works.

Initially, the store has version `1.9.1` but it was upgraded to `1.9.4` and everything works for around 8-10 months. Now the newly registered user is not able to log in. **All old user those have registered 24 hours before from current time are able to login**. I don't understand what is the problem

**Tests**

1) Registered a user with some dummy credentials. Then go to `PHPMyAdmin` in `customer_entity` table and changed the `created_date` to a day before. It works, but I don't understand why?

2) My site is running with `https` and `www`. So I changed the cookie domain to

```
i) .www.example.com
ii) www.example.com
iii) .example.com
iV) example.com
```

None of them is working. [image]

3) Tried after changing the timezone, nothing happens

4) Checked out the code and seems to be OK.

5) Taken help from more developers but they are also not able to find a solution.

Now I am helpless issue got more than 1 week and I do not know what should I do now. It will be great full if someone can help me out

Comment: Cookie domain should be *.example.com but that's not your problem. It's a timing or locale issue.

Comment: I have tried that too. The timezone I have selected is America/Los_Angeles from the store.